# parallax.js and animate.css -> onClick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax.js

I'm using `parallax.js` and `animate.css` for a project. I want to click on one red circle to fire a function, but the click event isn't working on them (or anything inside the `<ul>` layer).

I have tried so many things now and nothing has worked. The only thing to get it working is when I delete the height attributes of the `#scene <ul>` but then it doesn't look right.

**EDIT :** The circles should hide when I click on them. It's like a layer would lay over them but there is nothing.

Comment: Can you please clear the question ? What will happen when you click on red circle ?

Comment: sry...there will be an animation and the circles will hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with your Javascript here**

The problem is that your `<li>` elements are masking your red circles. Visually you can see them, but if you right-click and `Inspect Element` on one of your circles it will show your last `<li>` item. You can also check that your animations are working by writing in your console:

```
$('.c1').click()
```

You can usually fix this playing with their `z-indices`. I.e. Change the `z-index` of your circles to be higher and set the values of `z-index` on your other elements to be lower.

However, the issue seems to be that you have a each `circle` in a new `<li>` element. I was able to fix this on your site by having the following:

```
<div class="circle c1 animated"></div>
<div class="circle c2 animated"></div>
<div class="circle c3 animated"></div>
<div class="square s1"></div>
<div class="square s2"></div>
<div class="square s3"></div>
```

In one `<li>` element instead of having them in separate ones.

Comment: EDIT: does't work at all. i gave every layer a z-index of 1. when i changed it in chrome dev tools it worked -.-'

Comment: yes i know but i don't know how to solve the issue. That's my problem ;-)

Comment: that's it! now i know what in my thinking was wrong. I needed just on layer. The other ones build over each other. Finally i understand why this wasn't working. Thank you so much!